# Generate PDF from html template with fixed header & footer

Tags: php, pdf

I want to convert huge html documents, formatted with css, to PDF with fixed header and footer on every page. What is the best php based library to achieve this ?

Comment: https://docraptor.com/

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I want free solution.

Comment: by using mpdf library